# Where to put business logic when you don't have a specified model for that feature? Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I'm trying to improve my code OOP wise.
I have the tendancy to put some of my bussiness logic inside my Controller.

Some people told me this is not desirable.

I know that when you are working with Posts for example. You can simply put your bussiness logic in your `Post.php` Model.

I now have a feature where i upload an .xlsx file and it has to be checked and validated if the format of the .xlsx is correct.

It is currently inside `ScheduleController@storeDeliveryXlsx`.

But i don't have a specified model for this to store the validation inside?

Is this where Repositories design pattern is needed? Or is it fine to create a model that doesn't communicate with the database like: `DeliveryFile.php` where i put the logic that i later can use throughout my app like this: `DeliveryFile::validate($file);` or `DeliveryFile::upload(file);`.

I think i'm likely to re-use the same validation on the .xlsx for multiple instances. So i'd like to do something like `Model::validate($file);`. But i don't know where to put the code.

Comment: you want to check csv file header columns i.e valid or not ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, I would personally recommend using a Service. A service class is essentially for common functionality that you may repeat across multiple controllers. The **Service** Layer is a design pattern that will help you to abstract your shared logic to a common service i.e. our new Service Class.

So in your instance, you could have a Service class such as ExcelValidator and then use something like the following to structure your approach.

```
<?php

namespace App/Services;

class ExcelValidatorService
{

  public function validate($file) 
  {
    // our validate logic
  }

}
```

And then in your controllers or models, you can call the ExcelValidator service to implement your repeated validate logic.

Comment: I think this is similar to using repositories? Do you know the pros and cons of using Services over Repositories?

Comment: A repository is a facade for persistence to supply access to data/objects, it is used to decouple the way you store data / objects from the rest of the application. i.e. a repository pattern could be implemented to abstract the fact that we store objects in redis so that we could swap out our repository at a later date if we decide to persist data in MySQL. 

A service on the other hand provides common functionality generally limited to business logic to your controllers / models. i.e. we move the excel validation logic into a ExcelValidator service so that other controllers can use it.

Comment: I fixed it using services over repositories because i'm never planning to change the data supply. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Repository is not a facade. Those are two different patterns.

Comment: Was not referring to the facade pattern in this case. Simply explaining the repository pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase `I now have a feature` would keep on repeating itself in the course of the lifetime of the code you are writing. Having separate controller, service, model classes, OOP design, modular code would definitely help in that regard. Now it might be easier, but it will keep on becoming difficult with time

Answer (score 1):

Recently I faced a similar problem, in my case I need to use, as model, a Restful API.

In composer.json I added under autoload

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "MYCOMP\\": "app/MYCOMP/"
},
```

Under app folders I added MYCOMP folder with two subfolders Providers and Restmodels.

In config/app.php in providers array I added only:

```
MYCOMP\Providers\RestModelServiceProvider::class,
```

In app/MYCOMP/Providers/RestModelServiceProvider.php I register all providers and facades for my rest models:

```
public function register()
{
    $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();

    $models = glob( realpath(__DIR__."/../") ."/RestModels/*/*RestModel.php");
    foreach($models as $model){
        $bnmodel = basename($model);

        if($bnmodel !== "BaseRestModel.php" && $bnmodel !== "BaseFacadeRestModel.php"){
            list($n, $niente) = explode("RestModel.php", $bnmodel);
            list($bnnoext, $niente) = explode(".php", $bnmodel);
            $res = $n.'Repository';
            $fold = basename(dirname($model));
            $nc = "\\MYCOMP\\RestModels\\".$fold."\\".$bnnoext;  
            $this->app->bind($res, function($app) use ($nc) {     
                return new $nc;
            });               
            $loader->alias($res, $nc."Facade");
        }
    }
}
```

This code is specific for my project and for how I structured folders.
For all rest models I have two files:

- app/MYCOMP/RestModels/{ModelName}/{ModelName}RestModel.php
- app/MYCOMP/RestModels/{ModelName}/{ModelName}RestModelFacade.php

The only exceptions are: BaseRestModel and BaseFacadeRestModel these classes are extended by all RestModel and RestModelFacade. So I'd implement something like validate under BaseRestModel.

BaseFacadeRestModel just contains:

```
<?php

namespace MYCOMP\RestModels\Base;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class BaseFacadeRestModel extends Facade{
    private $facadeName;

    protected static function getFacadeName(){
        list($senzasuffisso, $niente) = explode("RestModelFacade", static::class);

        $nc = last(explode("\\", $senzasuffisso));
        return $nc;
    }

    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() {
        return static::getFacadeName().'Repository'; 
    }
}
```

So all the other Facades work just exteding BaseFacadeRestModel.